# Java annotation for request fields

Tags: java, validation, annotations

I have an API where I want to validate some `String` fields using a custom `@Annotation`. Validation should happen when the user sends the data. If validation fails, I want to throw an exception. Validation will be complex, as I want to check for SQL & HTML injections.

I got the following Request Object:

```
public class UserUpdateRequest extends BasicDataObject {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1295104288600535600L;
    
    // I would like to validate the firstName value upon receiving data
    @CustomValidator
    private String firstName;

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

}
```

This is my `BasicDataObject` :

```
@XmlRootElement
public abstract class BasicDataObject implements Serializable {

    /**
     * The generated serialVersionUID.
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 2876242398874879466L;
    
    // some more stuff
}
```

How would I achieve this? I know that I can create custom annotation interfaces like this:

```
@Target({ ElementType.TYPE, ElementType.METHOD })
@Retention(value = RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface CustomValidator {
    String value();
}
```

But I do not know where to actually put my validation logic so that it is called on every field that I annotate with `@CustomValidator`. I do not use Spring. Any help is appreciated!

**EDIT:**

This is my web adapter using `javax` where I get the `UserUpdateRequest`:

```
@Path("/users")
@Produces("application/json")
@Consumes("application/json")
@GlobalSecurityResponse
public class UserAdapter {

    @PUT
    @JWTSecured(tokenType = UserTokenTypeEnum.AUTH, permissions = { UserEndpointPermissionsEnum.ACTIVE })
    public Response updateUser(@Context SecurityContext securityContext, final UserUpdateRequest userUpdateRequest) {
        Principal principal = securityContext.getUserPrincipal();
        long userId = userBoundary.getPrincipalUserId(principal);
        UserLoginResponse userLoginResponse = userBoundary.updateUser(userId, userUpdateRequest);
        return Response.ok(userLoginResponse).build();
    }

}
```

Comment: Use reflection API to find annotated classes, then add your logic to the setter method with the API.

Comment: You can add a pre-validation method (in Spring using AOP) which intercepts the API requests, then using reflection you find the annotated fields and validate them.

Comment: How would I do that? I will put my web adapter in the original question

Answer (score 0):

You created interface but does not created validator class which will be used by that interface.
Your validation logic will go inside isValid method of validator class.
You can find implementation [here](https://dzone.com/articles/create-your-own-constraint-with-bean-validation-20)

Comment: I already tried it with this tutorial, but the validator class is never called when I send data. Is this because the `UserUpdateRequest ` extends `BasicDataObject ` which implements `Serializable `?